# How to split a string before the first letter in it and after it

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get separate numbers + special characters + letters from a string with numbers, letters, and special characters. My attempt

```
var chars = str.slice(0, str.search(/[a-zA-Z]+/));
var numbs = str.replace(chars, '');
```

The code does not work in case there are no letters.
example of how it should work

```
'123.331abc' -> '123.331' + 'abc'
'12331abc123' -> '12331' + 'abc123'
```

Comment: What is the *actual* question? Categorize characters into letters, digits and special characters or do a split right before the first letter?

Comment: @InSync split before the first letter

Comment: "The code does not work in case there are no letters" what does "does not work" mean? Because based on the code you wrote, you are first getting the substring before any letter _or when we run out of string to check_, which is _the entire string_ if there are no letters (you're not splitting, you're subsetting, and not checking the result of the subset) If you then blindly replace that with `''` then yeah: you just created an empty string. So don't replace anything if `chars` is the same as `str`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans string '12345' gives '1234' and '5'

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the both parts with a regex only:

```js
const arr = [
  '123',
  '123.331',
  '123.331abc',
  '12331abc123'
];

const splitBeforeLetter = str => str.match(/([^A-Za-z]+)(.*)/).slice(1);

console.log(...arr.map(splitBeforeLetter));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const test = "123.887azee7";
const firstLetterIndex = test.search(/[a-zA-Z]/); // return the index of the first letter found, "-1" otherwise
```

then you just use [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
if (firstLetterIndex !== -1) {
    const firstSubstring = test.substring(0, firstLetterIndex); //  out put 123.887
    const secondSubstring = test.substring(firstLetterIndex); // output azee7
} else {
    console.log('no letters founed');
    // or do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Match the first part, then `.slice()` to get the second:

```js
const [firstPart] = string.match(/^[^a-z]*/i);
const secondPart = string.slice(firstPart.length);
```

`^[^a-z]*` means 0 or more non-letter at the beginning. Due to the nature of the `*` quantifier, this will always match, resulting in a match array whose first element is the first part.

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const testcases = [
    '12331abc123',
    '123.331abc',
    'abc123',
    'abc',
    '123',
];

function splitBeforeFirstLetter(string) {
  const [firstPart] = string.match(/^[^a-z]*/i);
  const secondPart = string.slice(firstPart.length);
  
  return [firstPart, secondPart];
}

testcases.forEach(
  testcase => console.log(testcase, splitBeforeFirstLetter(testcase))
);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```